# How best to implement Grails Spring Batch domain object reader?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, spring-batch

In order to implement a reader/processor/writer pattern in Grails, where the reader needs to read in Grails domain classes, then process them, what is the best way to implement the reader?  Let's assume that the domain objects to be processed can be identified by means of some form of query / criteria.

Is it best to create a bean that implements `ItemReader`, which will do some sort of findBy of the domain objects, then return one of them?  This seems to me like there's a lot of query effort being expended for returning just a single record (the total result set will contain approximately 17 million records).

Or would it be better to do something like extend `AbstractPagingItemReader`?

Or use something like `JdbcCursorItemReader` and map the results to an class using a row mapper, as per [this example (non-Grails)](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-example-mysql-database-to-xml/)?

Or is there better way of doing this?